# Perl How to print unique pairs from a file

Tags: regex, arrays, perl

I am  trying to figure out how to print unique pairs of data from a file using Perl.

For instance,

```
Input: (check.pl)
A23072 A25058
A25058 A23072 
Output:
A23072 A25058
```

To tackle the task, I created a copy of the file check.pl and iterated through it to find the regular expression. I wrote the following code but I am unable to filter the data.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
open FH, "<check.txt" || die "Error\n";
open FH1, "<checkcopy.txt" || die "Error\n";
chomp (my @array=<FH1>);
my %count=();

while (<FH>) 
{
my @values = split;
next if grep /\D/, @values or @values != 2;

my $re = qr/\A$values[0]\s+$values[1]\z|\A$values[1]\s+$values[0]\z/;

   foreach my $key (@array) 
   {
      if ((grep $_ =~ $re, $key) && (grep ++$count{$_} == 1, $key) )
      {
        print "$key\n";
      }
   }    
}
1;
```

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store the values in a hash as well which makes looking them up much easier. Something like:

```
my %duplicates;
while (<>) {
  my @values = split;
  next if @values != 2;

  my @sorted  = sort @values;
  $duplicates{ $sorted[0] } ||= {};
  next if $duplicates{ $sorted[0] }->{ $sorted[1] };

  $duplicates{ $sorted[0] }->{ $sorted[1] } = 1;
  print join(' ', @values), "\n";
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what lines 5-7 are achieving here in this code?

Comment: It was supposed to store each member of the pair for looking them up for duplicated. However, that code was flawed. If you have a pair, a different pair with the same first member and then the original pair (e.g. the sequence "A B", "A C", "A B") then my original example would not recognize the third pair as a repetition of the first one. @ChrisCharley's example is better, though not perfect either for a general case. I'll modify my example in a moment.

Comment: Your previous code works correctly (I tried it myself with a sample file). I just wanted to understand what each step was doing because I am writing another code that compares TWO FILES (like the input here) and prints lines that match.

Comment: This code doesn't work if I have additional columns of data. Could you explain the code so I can change it for other applications?

Comment: The idea is to store each pair in a hash with the smaller value as the hash key. If that hash with this particular key contains that particular value then a pair has already been seen. So: each line is split into two parts which are then sorted alphabetically. The first element becomes the key, the second the value. If you need to adopt that for > 2 columns then you'll have to nest that hash structure deeper, something like `$dup{$sorted[0]}->{$sorted[1]}->{$sorted[2]}->{$sorted[3]}`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a technique I saw for a similiar problem using `sort`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %seen;
my @array;

while (<DATA>) {
    next unless 2 == (@array = split);
    my $key = join "", sort @array;
    print unless $seen{$key}++;
}

__DATA__
A23072 A25058
A25058 A23072
```